# context index with multi columns in oracle return no rows

Tags: oracle11g

I create context index with statement:

```
create TABLE test_context_index
(id number,
column1 VARCHAR2(30),
column2 VARCHAR2(30),
column3 VARCHAR2(30)
)
/
INSERT INTO test_context_index (ID,COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3) 
VALUES(1,'tinhah','test','test data');
INSERT INTO test_context_index (ID,COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3) 
VALUES(2,'tinehaeh','test 12','abc');
/
begin
ctx_ddl.create_preference('my_multi', 'MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE');
ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_multi', 'columns', 'column1, column2, column3');
end;


create index myindex on test_context_index(column1) 
  indextype is ctxsys.context 
  parameters ('DATASTORE my_multi');
```

I created successfully.
I run statement return no rows, help me!

```
Select * from test_context_index where contains (column1, 'h%') > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select * from test_context_index where column1 like '%h%';
```

Comment: i.e. you need a wildcard on both sides of the character

Comment: It mean contain h. If you want your left contain h you can 'h%'

Answer (score 0):

Put a `%` at the beginning as well as the end:

```
Select * from test_context_index where contains (column1, '%h%') > 0;


ID   COLUMN1    COLUMN2   COLUMN3
--   -------    -------   -------
1    tinhah     test      test data
2    tinehaeh   test 12   abc
```

The text index will still be used even with the wildcard at the beginning:

```
explain plan for Select * from test_context_index where contains (column1, '%h%') > 0;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);


Plan hash value: 2922841387

----------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name               |
----------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                    |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST_CONTEXT_INDEX |
|   2 |   DOMAIN INDEX              | MYINDEX            |
----------------------------------------------------------
```